# Where does the console command save exported file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I tried creating a custom command like this:

```
php artisan make:command app exportappresults
```

And the Command goes like this:

```
protected $signature = 'app:exportappresults';

protected $description = 'Export App Exam Result Into Excel';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    return Excel::download(new TavanmandAppUserExamExport,'userexamlist.xlsx');
}
```

So as you can see I have used Laravel Excel and tried exporting data into Excel file.

Note that this code works fine in the Controller and can properly export an Excel file.

But now I don't know where does the exported excel file from the DB goes when I use the Console Command.

So if you know, please let me know...

Thanks.

Comment: Would be cool if you showed `TavanmandAppUserExamExport` and `parent::` (so probably where this class is extended from) aswell..

Comment: check `storage/export`. If it is downloaded, check your download folder

Comment: @AbdullaNilam There is no `storage/export` folder

Comment: But why `command` to download a file? Make no sense. Search the file and see where it is.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Because it may took too long to export and sometimes it does not load at all because the data is so large

Comment: @Pouya create a JOB instead of a command. Best practise. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Excel::download` is used in HTTP controllers, to pass exported data to HTTP response. If you need to store file on disk, use `Excel::store` instead:

```php
public function handle()
{
    Excel::store(new TavanmandAppUserExamExport, 'userexamlist.xlsx');
}
```

File will be stored in default storage (disk), configured in laravel's `config/filesystems.php`, by default it's `./storage/app`.

Also you may specify another disk as third argument of `Excel::store` method, see [Storing exports on disk](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/store.html)

Comment: I tried that but didn't find any `userexamlist.xlsx` file in `storage/app` directory

Comment: Check write permissions of `storage/app`, and errors in laravel log. Also check which storage driver is used (variable `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` in `.env`, and storage paths in `config/filesystems.php`). Also try to explicitly set `local` as third argument of `Excel::store`